# How can I can deploy just one SSRS report at a time?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I just installed the latest version of SQL Server Design Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (in order to get SSIS templates etc.)

Prior to this I could right-click a report in Solution Explorer and choose *run*, and this would deploy and run just that one report, but not the others in the project.

Now it seems that when I do the same, all reports (and data sources) in the project are being re-deployed every time I try this. It's not a huge problem, but I liked the old way, in case somebody knows of a little setting tweak in there - I've not found it yet in search.

Comment: You don't have the right click and deploy option for individual reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully this bug was fixed in [Reporting Services Projects 1.18](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio#overview).

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem when we recently upgraded our setup.

The first thing to note is that `Run` isn't typically used as a deployment model. It's supposed to be something used for testing, so the behavior you're seeing is likely related (in part) to that. To actually deploy a report, you should be using `Deploy`, which is right above the `Run` option.

Additionally, we often saw this behavior when VS could not completely build the entire solution. If you have any reports in your solution that don't build, or are missing (as in they're in the solution but not on disk), the overall build "failed".

That means that VS will continue to try and rebuild the whole project each time you build, run, or deploy anything. If you remove everything from your solution that doesn't pass, and then do this once, you should notice that behavior goes away.

[image: Image of VS report item context menu.]

Comment: Ah great, I'll fix up any problems now. Do you think the data sources that are reporting 'Cannot deploy data source to the server because it already exists and OverwriteDataSources is not specified.' Will be among the culprits? Is there a way to exclude them from constantly being updated anyway, as there's no need at present.

Comment: Hmm, still can't get it to play ball. It is development and testing I'm using `run` for, but the trouble is we have so many reports in one of the projects, I keep having to wait on some 50 or so to deploy every time I make some little tweaks.

Comment: @Mikustykus we have roughly 1000 in a solution, so that shouldn't be a huge issue. Just to clarify, are you context clicking on the project as a whole or just the individual report?

Comment: Just right-clicking the individual report. Datasources are throwing the silly warning about already existing, and one or two warnings about overlapping boxes in other reports, but apart from that everything seems to deploy fine.